# Subgroup of all self inverse elements

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $H \leqslant G$ a subgroup of a group $G$ with following condition:

$H = \{ g \in G \vert g^{-1} = g \}$

Now I should show, that this is a subgroup of $G$. So far so easy. If I apply this to the permutation group $S_3$, it won't work anymore. E.g. let the two maps

$p_1 = \left(\begin{array}{3,2} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 1 & 3\\ \end{array} \right)$ and $p_2 = \left(\begin{array}{3,2} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 3 & 2\\ \end{array} \right)$

Both maps are the inverse element of itself, thus the condition would be true. But if we connect those maps, it will result following map:

$p_1 \circ p_2  = \left( \begin{array}{3,2} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3  & 1\\ \end{array} \right)$

This map is not inverse to itself, therefore it is not in $H$. This implies that the group is not closed and not a subgroup by definition. How is this possible?

Comment: This subset just isn't a subgroup in general, and as you say, $S_3$ is a counterexample. It is when $G$ is abelian, though.

Comment: Do you mean "Let $H \leqslant G$ a subset of a group $G$" in the first sentence?

Answer (score 4):

If we assume that $H$ is a subgroup and take two arbitrary elements $g, h\in H$, then we get
$$
(gh)(gh) = e\\
ghghh = h\\
ghg = h\\
ghgg = hg\\
gh = hg
$$
which means that $g$ and $h$ commutes.

It turns out that this is exactly what decides whether $H$ is a subgroup or not: whether all elements of $H$ commute with all other elements of $H$. (We clearly have $e\in H$, and by definition of $H$ we also have $h\in H \implies h^{-1} \in H$, so the only thing that isn't automatically fulfilled is closure under multiplication.) This is trivially satisfied if $G$ is abelian, and it is not satisfied for $G = S_3$, as you have noted yourself.